# Doctrine 2: How does UniqueObject validator work?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have problem with UniqueObject validator from DoctrineModule (v. 0.8.1). It always return true or throw an exception.

I have following structure in database:

```
 ______________________________________________
| id | user |      email       |     phone    |
|____|______|__________________|______________|
|  1 |  1   |  test@test.com   | 123456789    |
|____|______|__________________|______________|
|  2 |  2   |  0test@test.com  | 123456789    |
|____|______|__________________|______________|
```

My code:

```
$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\Entitymanager');
$validator = new \DoctrineModule\Validator\UniqueObject(array(
    'object_manager' => $em,
    'object_repository' => $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\User'),
    'fields' => array('email', 'user'),
    'use_context' => false    // <--- I also tried with true
));
```

From documentation:

> If you leave out the use_context option or set it to **false** you have to
>   pass an array containing the fields- and identifier-values into
>   isValid()

So, I run:

```
$validator->isValid(array('email' => 'test@test.com', 'user' => '1'));
```

Which throws an exception:

> Expected context to contain id

If I set **use_context** to **true**

From documentation:

> If you set the use_context option to **true** you have to pass the
>   **fields-values as first argument** and an array containing the
>   **identifier-values as second argument** into isValid()

Then:

```
$validator->isValid(array('email', 'user'), array('test@test.com', '1'));
```

**Always** return **true**, even when it shouldn't, That's because this line https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Validator/UniqueObject.php#L107 return following values:

```
array (size=2)
  'email' => string 'email' (length=5)
  'user' => string 'user' (length=4)
```

So it will always return true because there is no user with email named 'email'.

My question is:
**How the hell this validator works? Does anyone can provide working example and use case of this validator?**

I just wanted to use it for update user's email, but looks like I'll need to find other way to do it.

Comment: It says it needs an id, so try this: `$validator->isValid(array('email' => 'test@test.com', 'id' => '1'));` I bet it works then.

Comment: @Wilt is correct (and should have added an answer). The *identifiers* in Doctrine are the field(s) used to uniquely reference the entity, in most cases you only have one identifier `id` hence the error "Expected context to contain *id*", where `id` is the identifier value you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

In your data you need to include the field you want to check for uniqueness including the identifier field.

I quote [straight from the documentation](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/validator.md#uniqueobject):

> Second, you have to pass a value for every identifier your entity has got.

Your identifier column is `id` so you should send also a field `id`. This field is missing in your trials, hence the error message.

So try:

```
$validator->isValid(array('email' => 'test@test.com', 'id' => '1'));
```

I bet it works then.

Comment: I have tried with `id` before I posted that question, but it doesn't work correctly IMO. Or I don't understand this. I have entity **user** and **contact**. It's one to many relation i.e. One user may have many **different** emails. With ur solution it will always return **true** because it's check record `id` while it should check `user`'s id

Comment: @user1409508 Should you not use `NoObjectExists` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `'use_context' => true` and apply only one field to `'fields' => ['email']` (you can omit array if you want). Validator works correctly in this combination.

My validation config in ZF3:

```
[
    'email' => [
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'email',
        'validators' => [
            [
                'name' => \DoctrineModule\Validator\UniqueObject::class,
                'options' => [
                    'object_manager' => $om = $this->getObjectManager(),
                    'object_repository' => $om->getRepository(User::class),
                    'target_class' => User::class,
                    'use_context' => true,
                    'fields' => ['email'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
]
```